# C# - dynamic path to run BAT in subfolder

Tags: c#, dynamic, path

Please and hello, I need a your help to run two BAT files with my newly build EXE .NET form. Folder structure is like this:

..\Game\Language\cz.bat

..\Game\Language\en.bat

..\Form.exe

I need my "Form.exe" to run these two BAT files by pressing coresponding buttons. I know it has to do something with dynamic paths but sadly I don't know how to set it :(

```
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start (@"\Game\Language\CZ");
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(@"\Game\Language\EN");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Why I need this? I will provide my game to other players and they can unpack the archive with game anywhere in their PC and those paths will never be like C:\Downloads\Game... It works OK if I write whole adress to the CZ.bat or EN.bat ofc, but I can't do this because in another PC the path will be different.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`Application.ExecutablePath
Application.UserAppDataPath`

for dynamic paths

[see this Link  ♥](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/application-startup-and-executable-path/)

Comment: Because the paths are different on each person's computer, you can dynamically find and use paths with this propertys

Comment: MessageBox.Show(Application.ExecutablePath); Just test this code and you can see it

Comment: Thank you guys, this ofc pinpoints some ways, I checked it out but I have sadly no idea how to use these two commands in my case, sorry I have no skills in C#, but I need somehow simplify game translation, it's all set I just need a dialog window for users to choose among two languages :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) Property, which will give you access to the directory, your executable was launched from.

To have a dynamic path, you can use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) method, to combine CurrentDirectory path and paths to your language bat files, like this:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\Game\Language\CZ.bat"));
    this.Close();
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\Game\Language\EN.bat"));
    this.Close();
}
```